# Php Datetime convert to RFC 3339 string date to datetime type

Tags: php, datetime

I need a  datetime  as `RFC3339` its for an api request from their documentation

parameter type:datetime

format : RFC3339

example: `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Here is my code for convert datetime to RFC3339

```
$datetime= date("c", strtotime("2014-03-10 05:40:00"));
```

it gives `2014-03-10T05:40:00+01:00` ,but i will get error message from the    api it says wrong date parameter

`var_dump($datetime)` gives type as `string` but i need the type as `datetime` so how can i convert RFC339 string  date to datetime?

Comment: Try this format, `Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z`

Comment: try `$datetime= date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("2014-03-10 05:40:00"));`

Comment: check this and send this to your API and check what happen:- https://eval.in/596033

Comment: @chetan its worked

Comment: @BlessanKurien  it also produce string. So i am confused

Comment: But the api returns correct response

Answer (score 4):

Php has [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339) for most formats.  You can simply use

```
date(DATE_RFC3339);
```

or

```
date(DATE_ATOM);
```

`date('c')` is for a different format ISO 8601.

Also, there is no "datetime" type in php.  It's always going to return a string.